# Return to userform mainscreen when closing another userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have my main userform with multiple buttons, one is my runPlexButton, when that is clicked it opens another userform Desconexion, if Desconexion is closed i need to return to my main screen, before clicking the runPlex button, but when i close it my  macro continues anyways, how can i achive it? Ive tried with a public variable as my flag but the value doesnt return

```
Private Sub runPlexButton_Click()
 
Desconexion.Show

If VarDesconexion = True Then
VarDesconexion = False
Exit Sub
End If

'rest of code

End Sub
```

Desconexion code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

CheckBox_ML.Value = True
CheckBox_P.Value = True
CheckBox_S.Value = True
CheckBox_B.Value = True

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
VarDesconexion = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't accept any answer provided you before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `VarDesconexion` variable used in `runPlexButton_Click` is not that from `UserForm_QueryClose`.

You need to declare `VarDesconexion` in any project's module:

```
Public VarDesconexion As Boolean
```

to let it be a single variable accessible and used from anywhere.

Additionally use `Option Explicit` clause to track usage of variables.

[image]